# using python requests to retrieve freegeoip.net information

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I want to use the python requests library to get json data from freegeoip.net.

I am using the code

```
import requests

data = requests.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/4.2.2.2")
```

the interpreter just stalls on that command and it ctrl+C exits with a timeout error

I was was using subprocess curl to pull the information, but it's not working well with testing because of the verbose.

Is there anyway remove the verbose in curl (the download status information)

Any other ways to do it would be appreciated

Comment: I would look into why `requests` is stalling. I'm guessing a user-agent thing. I can access that URL fine from my browser, but not with `requests`.

Comment: it was working with curl but when i am running my unittest i keep seeing the curl download information. Is there a way to silent that info?

output = str(subprocess.check_output("curl "+urlString, shell=True))
output = output.split(",")
return str(output[1])

Comment: Curl's `-s` (or `--silent`) flag should do the trick. You could also redirect stdout in linux `curl -s 'http://example.com' > /dev/null`

Comment: But I'm really trying to figure out why `requests` is so slow! Same story with urllib. I used `selenium` with Chrome and Firefox and it worked instantly. Tried spoofing user agent with Requests, but no dice.

Comment: this code works for me without problems. maybe there was some problem on server.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

def get_Countrycode(S):
     urlString = "http://freegeoip.net/csv/"+S
     output = str(subprocess.check_output("curl --silent "+urlString,shell=True))
     output = output.split(",")
     return str(output[1])
```

This seems to be working better

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2
import json

data = urllib2.urlopen("http://freegeoip.net/json/4.2.2.2").read()
print data
djson = json.loads(data)
print djson['ip']
```

Just add the `.read()` method and you should be golden! Now you can also use json to get individual values as well via key, value pairs.